# Как можно убить программу в OSX?

Tags: macos, kill

Ситуация такая:

- OC - OSX HighSierra 10.13.3 (17D102).
- программа зависла, но закрылась. Программы не видно в TaskManager (pid ее неизвестен).
- активности программы в панели doc не видно, но при нажатии ПКМ есть поле ForceQuit. И это ForceQuit не закрывает программу.
- При попытке открыть программу она не открывается.
- При попытке закрыть программу через ForceQuitApplication (левый угол экрана) она не закрывается.
- При попытке перезагрузить систему OSX просит закрыть программу.

Как можно убить этот процесс помимо перезагрузки от кнопки?
Такая ситуация происходит достаточно часто и с разными программами.

Answer (score 0):

Найдите нужный вам процесс, выполнив `top` в терминале. В первой колонке можно найти его pid. Затем процесс можно завершить, послав ему сигнал SIGKILL. Снова через терминал (пусть ваш pid 12345:

```
kill -9 12345
```